# Hibernate does not work in the app console

Tags: java, hibernate

There was a problem after I connected the hibernate dependency to my project via the maven. Everything works in IntelliJ Idea, but if I run the jar from the console, then it throws me an error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.build(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.<init>(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:87)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid logger interface org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger (implementation not found in sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7f31245a)
```

I can’t understand what the reason for this behavior is. Here is the version I'm using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: How are you running this from the console? We need more details to help you. Maybe you are missing a JAR on the classpath.